# How to share single route53 domain across two or more amplify console apps

Tags: aws-amplify, amazon-route53

Here is what I did.

1. register a domain with aws route53 ( example xyz.com ) - DONE
2. create one website on bitbucket repo1 ( simple hello world html ) - DONE
3. create second website on bitbucket repo2 ( simple hello world html ) - DONE
4. create app on aws amplify console, link with bitbucket repo1 , deploy to custom domain (repo1.xyz.com) - DONE
5. create app on aws amplify console, link with bitbucket repo2 , deploy to custom domain (repo2.xyz.com) - FAILED

Step 5 fails with following error

Create domain association failed - One or more domains requested are already associated with another Amplify app

Is this setup possible? I am not able to find any document from AWS to say it is / is not.

The idea is that a single domain needs to server multiple apps, for example

- api.xyz.com --> serve rest api from aws api gateway
- auth.xyz.com --> aws cognito domain
- [www.xyz.com](http://www.xyz.com) --> public html website (managed by aws amplify console)
- webapp.xyz.com --> react app  (managed by aws amplify console)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps, I just run into the same problem and was able to resolve it.

You are getting this error because you have probably verified the DNS provider for both subdomains from the same app, using the CNAME provided by one of the apps (the "data" part of your CNAME would be the same for both subdomain's CNAME in this case). What you should do, instead, is verify ownership of the domain in either app, but then configure the DNS provider for each subdomain in the corresponding app.

App1: Verify domain.com (and [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com)) and subdomain for app1.domain.com
App2: Verify subdomain for app2.domain.com (and disable domain.com as its automatically added).

If you duplicate a subdomain verification in 2 or more apps, then you will see the error you mentioned above (this includes domain.com and [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com)).